# How to pass 2 or more different type parameters to jasper from java to ireport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to use java.struts2 to take two or more parameters to *JasperReports*'s master_report and subreport.

Here is my code snippet:

JasperAction.java:

```
private String Para_rin;
private String[] Para_rin_sub1;

public String CreateRep_rin() throws Exception {
     try {                      
            param_rin = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            param_rin.put("Para_rin", new Integer(Para_rin)); //  Masterreport's parameter
            param_rin.put("Para_rin_sub1", Para_rin_sub1); //  SubReport's parameter                        
            System.out.println("param_rin"+param_rin);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return ERROR;
         }
     return "jasper-rin";
}
```

master.jrxml:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["G:\\pages\\iReport\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="Para_rin_sub1" class="java.util.List"/>
<parameter name="Para_rin" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select * from iv_raw_in where ID=$P{Para_rin}]]>
</queryString>
```

subreport.jrxml:

```
<parameter name="Para_rin_sub1" class="java.util.List">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="Para_rin" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select * from iv_raw_in where $X{IN,ID,Para_rin_sub1}]]>
</queryString>
```

jsp:

```html
<s:form id="jasper" action="jasper_CreateRep_rin" namespace="/pages/iReport">
  <TABLE id="reptbl" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
      <td>
        MasterParam :<s:textfield name="Para_rin" label="Stock" />SubParam :<s:textfield name="Para_rin_sub1" label="sub-Parameters" />

        <s:submit value="Generate Stock Report" type="button" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <s:radio label="format" name="rptFmt" list="#{'html':'HTML','pdf':'PDF'}" value="pdf" />
      </td>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</s:form>
```

now I meet sth wrong like:

```
Database Connected
reportName: rep_rin
Format pdf  -- rptFmt  Exception::net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException:       Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : $P{Para_rin_sub1}.toArray()
```

how can I finish it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `subreportParameter` in your master.jrxml. See sample

```
<subreport>
    <subreportParameter  name="Para_rin_sub1">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Para_rin_sub1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
</subreport>
```

Comment: thx..but after I use your sample, I meet this:`Exception::net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
 Source text : $P{Para_rin_sub1}`

Comment: I think you also need to pass your subreport as parameter in both java class and master.jrxml

Comment: In my opinion, that's 2 problem here... **Firstly**,can not delivery parameters from main-report to sub-report.... **Secondly**,The dataType java.util.List is hard to pass between main-report with sub-report when use **'use a connection expression'** as **Connection Type.**